# Way of looping through DIVs and picking values from two different elements within

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an array of DIVs like so

```
<div id="item-14620">
<div>
<span class=""/>
<table border="0" width="100%" height="250">
<tbody>
<tr align="center">
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" title="some data here"></td>
    <td valign="top"><strong>some value here</strong> </td>
    <td valign="top" title="">
    <td valign="top">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="printThisItem">
</div>
```

another DIV in the same list of DIVs

```
<div id="item4569" >
<div>
<span class=""/>
<table border="0" width="100%" height="250">
<tbody>
<tr align="center">
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" title="some other data here"></td>
    <td valign="top"> <strong>Some other value</strong> </td>
    <td valign="top" title="">
    <td valign="top">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="printThisItem">
</div>
```

I am using an xpath like this

```
...FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[starts-with(@id,'item')]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/strong"))
```

to return a list of elements, but that only gets me values on the 4th row in the list of DIVs. There are some divs that have the required data on the 5th row and some that have it on the 4th row. How do I iterate thru all the divs and get values from row 4 where data is in row 4 and from row 5 when data is in row 5?

I thought of iterating thru the divs twice, once with `tr[4]` in the XPath and the second time with `tr[5]`, but then I also need the order in which they were found. With doing it one row at a time I get all the `tr[4]` items in a list followed by all the `tr[5]` items. But thats not how they are laid out in the page. There could be 3 items on row 4, then the next 2 on row 5 and the next 6 on row 4 again. I need to maintain the order as well.

Im using Selenium 2.53

Comment: Can you show the 4th/5th rows of div?

Comment: They are up there in the question within the two divs. One div has the forth row and the other has the fifth row with data i need.

Comment: I don't see a tag called `strong` in them? Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath -- `//div[contains(@id,'item')]//table//tr[4 or 5]/td")`. This will get you data in `td` tag according to order of display.

Comment: There are some cases where data is in both the rows, so will the `or` work ?

Comment: Should work for all cases... one row either 4th or 5th, both rows.

Comment: You will need to suffix it with the 'strong' tag at the end, missed it out in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This xpath should give you any second `td` containing `strong` under any `tr`

```
.//*[starts-with(@id,'item')]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/strong
```

So even if the `strong` is in any row you will get that.

Comment: Thanks. I think the above solution by grasshopper gives me more control on which rows I want to pull data off from. Thanks for your input anyways. It will be useful in other scenarios.